# vuejs redirect in controller

Tags: vue.js, routes

I'm not sure why the routing isn't working after I include my controller to component. So in my component `Login.vue` I have this code

```
...

<script>
import auth from '../controllers/auth'
...
methods: {
   ...
   return auth.doLogin(this);
```

and in my controller auth

```
doLogin(context) {
    axios.post('/post/doAuth', context.login, this.postHeadersJson).then(response => {
        ...

        this.$router.go(redirect);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
        context.errors.push({message: e.response.data.message});
    });
}
```

but I just see error that router is undefined. How to use it properly?

Answer (score 0):

So after more deep search I made up a solution without routing from controller. I made a direct route from component using promise to get response from controller.

```
// Login.vue
return auth.doLogin(this).then(success => {
                this.$router.push(success)
            });

// auth.js
doLogin(context, credentials, redirect) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post('/post/doAuth', context.login, this.postHeadersJson).then(response => {
    ...

    resolve(...);
}).catch(e => {
    reject(...)
});
    });
}
```